# How to hide the launcher when fullscreen apps like Freecol are running?

Tags: unity, launcher, fullscreen

Every time I run Freecol the Unity launcher appears and stays there on top of all apps and doesn't hide like it usually does. How to fix that?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).